# Requiring a gem with a system class naming conflict

Tags: ruby, require, class-names

I'm writing a build script in Rake that uses a couple of 3rd party gems. One of these gem defines a class called `Hash`.

```
class Hash
  alias hkeys keys

  def keys
    hkeys.sort {|a,b| a.to_s <=> b.to_s }
  end

  def each
    keys.each { |k| yield k, self[k] }
  end
end
```

This is breaking enumeration, resulting in `no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)`. I read that I can use `::Hash` to reference the core ruby type, but how would this fit with code like

```
bucket.objects.each do |obj|
  puts "#{obj.key} => #{obj.etag}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> One of these gem defines a class called `Hash`.

No, it doesn't. It modifies the existing `Hash` class.

> I read that I can use `::Hash` to reference the core ruby type

That is complete nonsense. `::Hash` simply says that constant lookup should start at the root (i.e. `Object`) instead of the current scope. This would only help if there were *two* constants named `Hash` and you wanted to disambiguate them. But in your case, there is only *one* constant named `Hash` and the gem is modifying the class referenced by that constant.

There is simply nothing you can do except don't use such crappy gems.